# tsql : how to do a substring replace?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

goal: I have the string "1234432144"  I want to only replace the first 2 4's with '10' so I would get '1231032144'

Is there a way to do this in tsql?

so far I have come up with the tsql substring() function

```
substring('1234432144', 4, 2)
```

which draws the 44 .. however how do i replace it within the existing string?

If i wrap a replace function around it, it replaces all occurrences of 44 in the string.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the criteria for replacing only the first 2 4s?

Comment: I just wanted a way to replace the first set of double 4's regardless of position and not have it repeating the replacement throughout the entire string. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited with a paremeterised version.

```
DECLARE @myStr VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @findStr VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @replaceStr VARCHAR(50)

SET @myStr = '1234432144'
SET @findStr = '44'
SET @replaceStr = '10'

SELECT STUFF(@myStr, CHARINDEX(@findStr, @myStr), LEN(@findStr), @replaceStr)
```

Comment: Of course it wont work if the requirement is to replace the first 4 with 1 and the second 4 with 0 rather than replace 44 with 10. In that case you would need to call the function twice.